# Display the needed Form

Tags: database, winforms

I'm newbie to C#. I am creating an application that when the user click the btnCreate, the default display is NewAccount form but if it is already have an account in database the display will be AdminPermission form then the NewAccount form. My problem is when I click the btnCreate, it display the AdminPermission form but i don't create any new account. below is my code:

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection connct = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\AcDatabase.accdb");
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM AccountDB", connct);

    if (cmd == null)
    {
        NewAccount nac = new NewAccount();
        nac.Show();
    }
    else if (cmd != null)
    {
        AdminPermission apf = new AdminPermission();
        apf.Show();
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want the New Account window to show when there are no rows returned?

If so you need to execute that OleDbCommand that you just created. But there are other issues with your code e.g. not opening the connection, I would advise you read this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306572

and this

http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataadapter/selectcommand-oledb.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM AccountDB WHERE name =@name", connct);
cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("name",txtName.Text);

if((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1)   //Account Exists
{

}
else
{

}
```